# How to modify .dvc/tmp location

Tags: dvc

I am running dvc inside a container where .dvc folder is read only. Whenever I try to do a dvc pull, it will try to crate `.dvc/tmp` which is not possible. How can I configure this location to /tmp? I have tried to set `state.dir` and `index.dir` but that is not enough. As it wants to write the `.dvc/tmp/lock` file in there.

Comment: I checked the code briefly. I don't think it's possible atm. The request makes sense to me. There should be probably a config option `tmp.dir`. Please feel free to create a GH issue for that or contribute (I don't expect this to be very involved). As a workaround for now - can you try to make it a symlink when you create a container? Or is there a way to make the directory writable, what is the limitation there?

Comment: I had a similar issue and I tried to replace the folder `.dvc/tmp` by a symlink poiting to a writeable location. Unfortunately, this produces errors when I try `dvc exp run --temp`. Apperently, the temporary copies of the repository, that are created for the experiment do not find the original .dvc folder, as there is no way to know for the temp-copies that they should follow back a symlink rathr then climb up in the hierarchy of directories. Addressing this in a GH issue seems reasonable to me.